# How to center accordion in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

button.accordion
{
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 12%;
    text-align: middle;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

 div.panel {
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: White;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<center><h2>Alcohol</h2></center>
<center><p>Click on the buttons to open the information.</p></center>

<button class="accordion">Beer</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p> Beer</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Wine</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Wine</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"> Wiskey</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Wiskey</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function()
  {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
     panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
     panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hey I was wondering if someone can help me center the accordion.
I can center the text  in the middle by using `middle` / `center`, but I can not seem to center the accordion. I tried using: `left: 50%` and `right: 50%` and some more options but none of them worked.

Comment: Please paste your code rather than using a screenshot, and show us the html as well, this is just the css.

Comment: Try using `text-align:center` instead of `text-align: middle` on your parent accordion class. Although without seeing your HTML, it's impossible to tell what is where and how they are being applied.

Comment: Sorry, but what happened between putting the h1 and the p in <center> elements, and posting here about not being able to center the buttons as well? I expected to see the buttons in <center> elements too! That would have worked, even. It's not recommended, but it would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I added a container which holds all of your accordion divs. This is the item that gets centred now.

```
.container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  width: 12%;
  }
```

I also set its width to 12% and the accordions to 100%, which in turn inherits to be 12%.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  width: 12%;
  }
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: middle;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
div.panel {
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: White;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h2>Alcohol</h2>
</center>
<center>
  <p>Click on the buttons to open the information.</p>
</center>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Beer</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Beer</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Wine</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Wine</p>
  </div>

  <button class="accordion">Wiskey</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>Wiskey</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put everything inside a div and use text-align center.

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
    <!-- Here is your accordion -->
</div>
```

Here is your code working. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gianemi2/fxkskneh/)